# Update View - Page not found

Tags: django

I am attempting to create an update view for a build log(subpost).

My URL structure is `/post/pk/buildlog/pkz/update`

The error I am getting is

```
Page not found
Raised by:  blog.views.UpdateBuildLog
...
post/<int:pk>/build-log/<int:pkz>/update/ [name='build-log-update']
The current path, post/118/build-log/53/update/, matched the last one.
```

view

```
class UpdateBuildLog(UpdateView):
    model = BuildLog
    form_class = BuildLogupdateForm
    template = 'blog/buildlog_update.html'
```

url

```
path('post/<int:pk>/build-log/<int:pkz>/update/', UpdateBuildLog.as_view(), name='build-log-update')
```

I believe the error is being caused because of the two primary keys not being passed into the view but I cant figure out how to pass the second primary key(pkz) into the view

Comment: Are you sure you have a `BuildLog` instance in your database with `pk=118`?

Comment: @Selcuk yes checked and verified

Comment: Can you double check?

Comment: Yup I have a buildlogid=53 with a post_id=118

Comment: Please read my comment again. You should have a `BuildLog` with `id=118`. We don't even know what `post_id` is. The point of a `pk` (primary key) is that it should be the primary identifier, and unique. Why do you need a second identifier?

Comment: Ah ok I changed the id to 118 and it worked.  The url structure of the site is `/post/pk/buildlog/pkz/update` so it looks like its taking the pk which is associated with the post and not the pkz which is associated with the buildlog. Is it possible to change the view to take the pkz instead of the pk?

Comment: You can change the URL definition to `'post/<int:pkz>/build-log/<int:pk>/update/'` but why do you need the `pkz`? It is not used anywhere.

Comment: the pkz is the pk of the buildlog so when the user is on their post they can then view the buildlogs associated with that post

Comment: I can't say anything more until you post all the relevant models as your comments are really confusing. `pkz is the pk of the buildlog`: This is clearly wrong as indicated by the original error message in your question.

Comment: Just figured it out I was passing the ids backwards via a button. Thanks for your time